# Django: Run scripts from admin by selecting object's name

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, web, admin

I am using Django 1.8 and Python 2.7.8 to create a web interface with MySQL databases, I can just use the Admin page to manipulate different tables. Suppose I have a student object with fields: name, id and gender.  How to achieve some function like this:

- select student's name: just avoid typo in names
- click a button like "Run script"
- trigger a Python program to run

I only need output from that Python program like: success or failure.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are after is admin actions. You write a custom function in the admin, and assign the function name to the `admin_actions` property.

```
def incomplete_tasks(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    queryset.update(completed=False)
incomplete_tasks.short_description = 'Mark as Not Complete'

class TaskAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['title', 'completed']
    ordering = ['created']
    actions = [incomplete_tasks,]

admin.site.register(Task, TaskAdmin)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/actions/

https://godjango.com/78-custom-django-admin-actions/